# From XMPP and RabbitMQ what should i use for group chat?

Tags: xmpp, chat, rabbitmq, ejabberd, erl

I am developing a chat application for android and i phone . Here i am to make persistent groups like whatsapp where members remain joined even after they get offline and after getting online they get their offline group messages. As it is not possible with XMPP so i am thinking about to go for rabbitmq and ejabberd both.

Here is how i want to make group-

1. When a group is created , an exchange is created in rabbitmq and each group members will add this user to its roster.
2. Now when a user send a message to rabbitmq then it will be delivered to members who are subscribed to that exchange and offline messages will remain in the queue till user gets online.

My Questions are-

> Is it the correct way which i am thinking? 
>   How much exchanges can we create in rabbitmq and how much memory an exchange takes ? 
>   How much messages a queue can store and how much memory it takes?
>   Should i use it or simply go with XMPP-MUC for group chat?

Comment: You can use topics with a single exchange (dont need one exchange per group). Messages on queues are supposed to be transient, it is not a data store. The limit is the RAM available.

Comment: is there any disadvantages on using it?